# Remove validation on fields from another partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have two partial views in my application. One contains a select list to decide between payments methods. If the user chooses Direct debit another partial opens with the relevant input fields and validation. If they choose Cheque this form is hidden. However the validation isn't removed

Direct Debit Partial View

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Sort Code", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SortCode12, new { @class = "control-label col-md-1", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                <div class="col-md-1"> - </div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SortCode34, new { @class = "control-label col-md-1", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                <div class="col-md-1"> - </div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SortCode56, new { @class = "control-label col-md-1", @readonly = "readonly" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SortCode12, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SortCode34, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SortCode56, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Account Number", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.BankAccountNumber, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @readonly = "readonly" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankAccountNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Account Name", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.BankAccountName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-10", @readonly = "readonly" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankAccountName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Payment method partial view

```
 <div id="CurrentPaymentMethod">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="cl panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    Payment Method
                </h4>
            </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Payment Method", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                           @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.PaymentMethodID,
                                                   new SelectList(Model.PaymentMethods, "Id", "Description"),
                                                   "Select Payment Method",
                                                   new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @onchange = "ChangePaymentMethod(this.value)" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentMethodID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
<script>
function ChangePaymentMethod(paymentMethodID)
{
    @* Show Direct Debit section if the DD payment option (ID=0) has been selected*@
    if (paymentMethodID == 0) {
        document.getElementById("CurrentDirectDebitDetails").style.display = "block";

    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("CurrentDirectDebitDetails").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("SortCode34").removeAttribute("data-val-required");
        document.getElementById("SortCode12").removeAttribute("data-val-required");
        document.getElementById("SortCode56").removeAttribute("data-val-required");
        document.getElementById("BankAccountNumber").removeAttribute("data-val-required");
        document.getElementById("BankAccountName").removeAttribute("data-val-required");
    }
}
```

At the bottom I have created some javascript to show and hide the direct debt from depending on the drop down selection item. This works however the validation remains

Any help with this would be appreciated

Comment: Use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` or similar conditional validation attribute applied to your properties

Answer (score 0):

You can give specific class Name for all validation messages, errorMessagesForm1 form2 etc ... 
then using this class to select the messages and hide it or remove it or whatever you want to do with it.

something like this,

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentMethodID, "", new { @class = "text-danger ErrMsgsForm2" })
```

js

```
var ErrorMSGs= document.getElementsByClassName("ErrMsgsForm2"); 
    // Array of all error messages, loop through it
    for(var i = 0; i < ErrorMSGs.length; i++){
        ErrorMSGs[i].style.visibility = "hidden"; // or any other method, maybe change innerHTML  etc 
    }
```

Comment: That will not work - the model is still invalid and the form cannot be submitted - but know the user has not the faintest idea what is going on since no errors are visible

Comment: @StephenMuecke my point was hiding the errors for the validation of the form he isn't using, not for all, and once we get back to that form, he should show it again.  
is that bad idea ?

Comment: Yes. And hiding the error text does not stop the `$.validator` from being invalid (and because its invalid the form will not be submitted back to the server and the poor user is stuck in limbo not knowing whats going on). OP needs to use conditional validation attributes

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh I misunderstand his question,  I thought when he is changing the form, the error messages are stacking from different forms,  
Thanks for the explanation